# Error when integrating Ionic2 Auth service

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to integrate Facebook login to my ionic 2 app. I was following the [guide here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/facebook-auth.html) and all is good until I stared to using `Auth` and `User` in the constructor.

The problem is, currently it's complaining the TypeScript cannot find the name `Auth` and `User`. However I do import:

`import { Auth, User } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';`

Following is my full code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, User } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public auth: Auth, public user: User, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

}
```

[image]

I'm running on

```
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic Native: 2.2.11
Ionic App Scripts: 0.0.47
Angular Core: 2.2.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1
Node: 6.1.0
OS Platform: OS X El Capitan
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: have you installed ionic-cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `cloud-angular` providers,
you have to setup ionic cloud client. Check [here](http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html)

`npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save`

will get you the providers you need.

Comment: Yep that was it... I installed and configured cloud-angular with the APP details (E.g ID etc..) all good, thanks

Comment: Hi, I am facing same situation but i tried your solution ..I am getting error : - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "ionic-native"

Comment: @Anuj update cloud-angular to latest version.  The older one might have ionic-native 2.x dependency

Comment: How to update that .please write down that command so i can work on it , thanks in advance

Comment: `non install @ionic/cloud-angular@latest --save` remove the older one first @Anuj

Comment: thanks , i did npm uninstall @ionic/cloud-angular --save then install latest command and i get ionic native installed but still issue is same :(

Comment: can you create a question with your error msg and package.json?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428177/error-on-integrating-of-ionic2-auth-service