# Error on integrating of Ionic2 Auth service

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to integrate facebook login to my ionic 2 app. I was following the guide [here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/twitter-auth.html) and all is good until I stared to using Auth and User in the constructor.

The problem is , currently when i use  `public auth: Auth, public user: User` in my constructor then it give issue

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "ionic-native"

Following is my full code

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, User } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'social-auth',
  templateUrl: 'social.html',
})
export class SocialAuth {
  constructor(public auth: Auth, public user: User) {
  }
  openTwitter(){
    this.auth.login('twitter').then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

My package json is

```js
{
  "name": "ionic-app-base",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js",
    "minify": "ionic-app-scripts minify --cleancss ./config/cleancss.config.js",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.10.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/paypal": "^3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/sim": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.10.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.6.1",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionic-debug-console": "^0.1.0",
    "ionic-native": "^3.5.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

and when I am installing ionic clound then this is i am getting :-

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I dont think you need to set `Auth` as provider again..It will taken care of by the Cloud module

Comment: HI Suraj , Thanks . It works . shown twitter login page    and getting token from there .. So  can i get everything from that token  . like tweets,user info .etc?

Comment: that I am not sure.. havent worked with twitter sdk yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an  invalid package in your **package.json**.

```
"ionic-native": "^3.5.0",
```

From version 3.x,
`ionic-native` is split into `@ionic-native/core` and `@ionic-native/package_name`.So `ionic-native 3.x` does not exist.

Remove the `"ionic-native": "^3.5.0",` entry from your package.json.

Clear node_modules folder and run `npm install`

Also as mentioned in my comment:
you *dont* need to set Auth as provider again..It will be taken care of by the Cloud module

Comment: ok so first i will delete using npm uninstall ionic-native --save and then delete node module folder from the file and then npm install . Right ?

Comment: you can do that too.. removing the entry and clearing node modules will do the uninstalling part anyway.. This way you know what is installed is exactly what is there in your package.json

Comment: ok for cleaning it i found rm -rf node_modules/
and then npm install  . i will do this and let you know, thanks

Comment: that issue resolved but now getting Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

Comment: that could be a different issue.. You can verify your package.json with the [starter app json](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json) for any mistakes...

Comment: HI Suraj , It may work now , getting ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Auth!
. Shoud i define it Auth in app.module.ts

Comment: defined it in app.module.ts but getting now Runtime Error
Can't resolve all parameters for Auth: (?). :(

Comment: can you add your app.module.ts to the question?

Comment: added,please look